# Generate a new variable based upon the values of the previous and next row by group

Tags: r

I am using panel data with multiple subjects (`id`) and have an event (`first_occurrence`) that occurs on different days.  My goal is to create a new variable (`result`) that is 1 on the 2 days preceding the `first occurrence`, the day of the `first occurrence`, and the 2 days following the `first occurrence`.

Here is an example that includes both the sample data and the desired output:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), first_occurrence = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), desired_output = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("id", 
"day", "first_occurrence", "desired_output"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Although this may not be the most efficient solution, I managed to get the code working in Stata (please see below for Stata code), although I would like to get it working in R as well and would appreciate any thoughts folks have.

Thanks!

Stata code:

```
tsset id day
    gen run = .
        by id: replace run = cond(L.run == ., 1, L.run + 1)

gen test = .
    replace test = run if(first_occurrence == 1)

gen test2 = .
    by id: replace test2 = test[_n-1]
gen test3 = .
     by id: replace test3 = test[_n-2]
gen test4 = .
    by id: replace test4 = test[_n+1]
gen test5 = .
    by id: replace test5 = test[_n+2]

egen test_sum = rowtotal(test test2 test3 test4 test5)
replace test_sum = 1 if(test_sum >= 1)
    rename test_sum result

drop run test test2 test3 test4 test5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using the package `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)        #install and load the package

data %.%
  arrange(id, day) %.%    # to sort the data by id and day. If it is already, you can remove this row
  group_by(id) %.%
  mutate(n = 1:n(),
         result = ifelse(abs(n - n[first_occurrence == 1]) <= 2, 1, 0)) %.%
  select(-n)

#   id day first_occurrence desired_output result
#1   1   0                0              1      1
#2   1   1                0              1      1
#3   1   2                1              1      1
#4   1   3                0              1      1
#5   1   4                0              1      1
#6   1   5                0              0      0
#7   1   6                0              0      0
#8   1   7                0              0      0
#9   2   0                0              0      0
#10  2   1                0              0      0
#11  2   2                0              1      1
#12  2   3                0              1      1
#13  2   4                1              1      1
#14  2   5                0              1      1
#15  3   0                0              0      0
#16  3   1                0              0      0
#17  3   2                0              0      0
#18  3   3                0              0      0
#19  3   4                0              1      1
#20  3   5                0              1      1
#21  3   6                1              1      1
```

What the code does is, first group by `id` and then it will add another column (`n`) where it counts the rows per group from 1 to the number of rows per group. Then it creates another column `result` with an `ifelse` that will check the absolute difference between the current `n` (for each row) and the `n` where `first_occurrence` is 1. If that difference is equal to or less than 2, result will be 1 otherwise 0. The last line removes the column `n`.

Edit:

It would probably be more efficient to place the `mutate(n = 1:n())` before the `group_by`:

```
data %.%
  arrange(id, day) %.%    # to sort the data by id and day. If it is already, you can remove this row
  mutate(n = 1:n()) %.%
  group_by(id) %.%
  mutate(result = ifelse(abs(n - n[first_occurrence == 1]) <= 2, 1, 0)) %.%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: Very interesting approach -- thanks for the thorough description and the neat use of the new dplyr package.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. You can use `ave` to look by group, and then you can use `which.max` to find the first occurrence and then calculate the distance from that value for all the other values

```
close<-(with(data, ave(first_occurrence, id, FUN=function(x) 
    abs(seq_along(x)-which.max(x)))
)<=2)+0
```

Here I use `+0` to turn the logical values into 0/1 values. Now you can combine that with your existing data

```
cbind(data, close)
```

And that gives

```
   id day first_occurrence desired_output close
1   1   0                0              1     1
2   1   1                0              1     1
3   1   2                1              1     1
4   1   3                0              1     1
5   1   4                0              1     1
6   1   5                0              0     0
7   1   6                0              0     0
8   1   7                0              0     0
9   2   0                0              0     0
10  2   1                0              0     0
11  2   2                0              1     1
12  2   3                0              1     1
13  2   4                1              1     1
14  2   5                0              1     1
15  3   0                0              0     0
16  3   1                0              0     0
17  3   2                0              0     0
18  3   3                0              0     0
19  3   4                0              1     1
20  3   5                0              1     1
21  3   6                1              1     1
```

as desired. Note that this method assumes that the data is sorted by day.